# Datadog - possible to transform a metric tag?

Tags: datadog, atlas

I am using Atlas MongoDB integration with Datadog, and have no control over the metrics it produces or their tags.

All the metrics we do have control over are tagged with environment, making dashboards very easy to be environment-agnostic

eg.

```
env = dev / test / prod
```

We have structured our Atlas where environment are segregated by "project", and conveniently all metrics are emitted with this as a tag.

```
project = development / non-production / production
```

However to chart these metrics on the same dashboard, it would be great if i could transform those tags to our standards, is this possible?

eg

```
project=development > env=dev
```

i have reviewed the UI and the documentation and cannot find anything